# How to use selenium webdriver to click on links

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use `selenium webdriver` to get all links from the page that have the property `a[href*=/simulation/form/]` and then open and close each of them?

I tried the following code but it returns `TypeError: link.click is not a function`

```
var simLinks = driver.findElements(By.css('a[href*=/simulation/form/]'));

for(var link in simLinks){
  link.click();
  driver.wait(30000);
  driver.back();
}
```

If I do `console.log(simLinks.length)` it returns `undefined`

Instead, it works perfect if I try to open a single link of that type:

```
var simLinks = driver.findElement(By.css('a[href*=/simulation/form/]')).click();
```

Comment: what is the type of simLinks?

Comment: simLinks should contain all elements with property `'a[href*=/simulation/form/]`...

Comment: I see that in Java it would be done like `List<WebElement> simLinks = driver.findElements(By.css('a[href*=/simulation/form/]'));`, but I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `util.inspect()` function to inspect objects:

```
const util = require('util');
...
console.log(util.inspect(simLinks));
```

Once you do that, you will see that `simLinks` is a `ManagedPromise`, so you need to change your code as follows to make it work:

```
driver.findElements(By.css('a[href*="/simulation/form/"]')).then(function (simLinks) {
  for (let link of simLinks) {
    link.click();
    driver.wait(until.urlContains('/simulation/form/', 30000));
    driver.navigate().back();
  }
});
```

The problem with that, however, is that only the first click works, but once you navigate back there is a legitimate `StaleElementReferenceError` - the page has indeed changed and the next element in the loop is no longer attached to the visible page. Therefore, a better strategy would be to collect the link addresses instead and use these with `driver.navigate().to(link)`:

```
driver.findElements(By.css('a[href*="/simulation/form/"]')).then(function (simLinks) {
  var hrefs = simLinks.map(link => link.getAttribute('href'));
  for (let link of hrefs) {
    driver.navigate().to(link);
    driver.wait(until.urlContains('/simulation/form/', 30000));
    driver.navigate().back();
  }
});
```

Comment: I still got that error `TypeError: link.click is not a function`, but the good thing is that the console returns 2 `WebElement` objects, which are my links

Comment: Ah, indeed, `simLinks` is an array. I fixed the answer accordingly, should work now :).

Comment: Thank you, this should do it but now it throws `ElementNotVisibleError`. How comes that the element is not visible since it gets logged in the console?

Comment: FYI I also tried to get the links as follows `By.css('a[data-ga-name="Property Summary: Edit Simulation"]'`.

This is how a link looks on the page: `<a href="/simulation/form/15760?p=7747&amp;t=3" data-ga-name="Property Summary: Edit Simulation">`

Comment: I tried the example with Google and the first click works. But once you navigate back there is a legitimate `StaleElementReferenceError` - the page has indeed changed and the next element in the loop is no longer attached to the visible page. I'll think a bit how to deal with this...

Comment: Glad I could help :)!

Comment: Do you also know how can I add a simple alert to the page when the code inside loop is executed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using:

console.log(simLinks.size())

I don't know if the () is required in javascript - it is in java.

Comment: I'm using `javascript`, not `java`